Canonical module of a squarefree monomial ideal
I am trying to understand Theorem 4 from the paper by Grabe (The canonical module of a Stanley-Reisner ring, https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(84)90066-8). This theorem describes the canonical module of the coordinate ring of a squarefree monomial ideal. However, I am struggling with the definitions provided in Section 2.1, especially because the notations for homological tools are not entirely standard. Specifically, I am unclear about the following notations:
$$H^i_m(R),\ \varinjlim_t H^i(x^t, R),\ H^i(\varinjlim_t (-) ) $$
These definitions seem to reference the book "Herzog and Kunz, Der kanonische Modul eines Cohen-Macaulay-Rings, Lecture Notes in Mathematics No. 238, Springer-Verlag, 1971". Unfortunately, this book is in German, which I do not understand.

Can someone familiar with these tools provide a detailed explanation of these notations or point me to a reference where they are explained thoroughly?

Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

It is better to ask one question at a time, so I suggest to split your two questions. That is, remove the content of the 2nd question from this one and post it separately. For the 1st one: are you familiar with the concepts of local cohomology and direct limit (colimit)?

Ok, thank you for the suggestion. I'll do that.

I'm familiar with the notion of homology of a simplicial complex and homology of a complex no with but local cohomology and direct limit... I don't know if there is a kind of relations seeing the terminologies
